# Rails JSON API, how to deal with nil object in RABL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, rabl

I have a Rails API that I'm using with RABL to send JSON back to the client.  I need to have a `show` and `index` action for a `Question` model. In this example, a `Question has_many Answers.`

How do you deal with a nil object in RABL? The API throws an error because I'm calling `.answers` on a `question` object that is `nil` (the `question_id` passed in doesn't exist).

I could wrap the association part of the RABL with an `if` like below so a `question` that doesn't exist won't cause an error,

```
# questions/show.rabl
object @question
attributes :id, :text

node(:answer_id) do |question|
    if question != nil     # <-- This if keeps the .answers from blowing up
        answer = question.answers.first
        answer != nil ? answer.id : nil
    end
end
```

But, then when I call `/api/questions/id_that_doesn't_exist` I get this returned: `{answer_id:null}` instead of just `{}`.

I tried wrapping the entire node element in an `if` like this,

```
if @question != nil    # <-- the index action doesn't have a @question variable
    node(:answer_id) do |question|
        answer = question.answers.first
        answer != nil ? answer.id : nil
    end
end
```

But then my `index` action won't return the `node(:answer_id)` because `@question` doesn't exist when calling from a collection.

Is there a way to get both behaviors?

```
# questions/index.rabl
collection @questions

extends "questions/show"
```

Comment: how about have if statement in your controller and explicitly render empty object there?

Comment: That seems a little hacky but it does make the error go away. If I return `{}` if the object is nil I get `[]` back from the call.  That might be a better solution than an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the answer in the RABL documentation trying to solve another issue.

You can add an `:unless` block to keep it from blowing up trying to access properties on a nil object:

```
# questions/show.rabl
object @question
attributes :id, :text

node(:answer_id, unless: lambda { |question| question.nil? }) do |question|
    answer = question.answers.first
    answer != nil ? answer.id : nil
end
```

Section in documentation: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#attributes